# Access current post parent and sub category

Tags: categories

I need to show in the each post his parent category and sub category, at the moment I use this code:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();

echo 'Parent Category: <a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a> \n';

echo 'Sub Category: <a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[1]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[1]->name ) . '</a>';
?>
```

The problem is that this code gives categories[0] and categories[1] values based on their order. In some post the order is Parent -> Sub, in others is Sub -> Parent (don't know why). So when I access $categories[1] in some posts I get the parent instead of the sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li> Parent Category: ';
foreach( $categories as $category ){
     if($category->parent != 0){
          $parent_category = get_term( $category->parent );
          echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link($parent_category->term_id)) . '">' . esc_html($parent_category->name) . ' </a>';
          break; 
     }
}
echo '</li>';
echo '<li>Subcategory: ';
foreach( $categories as $category ){
     if($category->parent != 0){
          echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link($category->term_id)) . '">' . esc_html($category->name) . ' </a>';
     }
}
echo '</li></ul>';
```

This works pretty well if your post's categories have the same parent category (e.g Your post has the categories 'child_1' and 'child_2' which are both children of the category 'parent_1'). It checks each of your post's categories. In the first `foreach`-loop, as soon as a category has a parent category it will be echoed and the loop will be left because of the `break`.
But if your post has multiple categories with different parent categories (e.g Your post has the category 'child_A_1' which is a child of 'parent_A', and the category 'child_B_1' which is a child of 'parent_B') this code won't work correctly since it would only echo the parent-category of the first subcategory that occurs in the first `foreach`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to fix it so it makes more sense to you.

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();

$rev_categories = array_reverse( $categories );

echo 'Parent Category: <a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a> \n';

echo 'Sub Category: <a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[1]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[1]->name ) . '</a>';
?>
```

If you are absolutely sure that you're never going to have an instance where $categories[1] won't exist, then your code will be fine, but I'd want to change it, run a `foreach` loop on all your categories, changing the label if the `$key` is 0.

```
foreach ( $rev_categories as $key => $category ) {
    echo ( $key == 0 ? 'Parent' : 'Sub' ) . ' Category: <a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>';
}
```